# Regex to include everything under root folder except for 2 folders?

Tags: regex, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog that I want to redirect to a new non-Wordpress blog. I have a plugin called [Redirection](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) that allows me to target a source URL with regex and redirect it to a target URL.

Currently, I have it set up as this:

- Source: /.*
- Target: http://mywebsite.com

This works fine but I am now unable to access Wordpress because http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin redirects me to my new website.

What regex value should I put down as the source URL so that I target everything under root except for folders:

- wp-admin
- folder1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use negative lookahead for this:

```
Source: ^(?!.*/(wp-admin|folder1))/.*
```

`(?!.*/(wp-admin|folder1))` is [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts a failure if `/wp-admin` or `/folder1` is found anywhere in source URI.